# Why does my Bluetooth dongle use more current when paired than when idle?

Tags: power, current, bluetooth, rf

I have a Bluetooth dongle which is connected through USB to my PC. I wanted to measure the current drawn so I connected an ammeter in series with the 5V line and am measuring the current. I observe some strange readings:

When I pair it takes up less current than when in idle state. This seems strange and I would like to know why.

Comment: Having almost no experience with BT this is just an educated guess. Before it has been paired it's probably doing some sort of scanning / searching. BT can only be paired with one node at a time so once it has been paired it no longer needs to do that and the transceiver will be off most of the time.

Comment: So that means after I pair with one node the current should drop down again. But for some reason that doesnt occur. It reduces when paring and hits the roof again

Comment: This is not a trivial subject, but a lot would depend on duty cycle and mode.  Some radios of this sort actually draw more power when receiving than transmitting, as they emit very little RF power but do a lot of processing to receive.

Comment: @DeveloperAndroid Ah, ok then it looks like my guess was wrong. In that case it is probably something more complex like Chris Stratton suggests and hopefully somebody with a more detailed knowledge of the BT protocol can answer.

Comment: Your title contradicts the question

Answer (score 2):

When unpaired, it is constantly scanning for a list of previously connected devices, and periodically advertising itself, requiring power for transmission.

When paired, it only listens to the paired device, and may broadcast "keep-alive" signals when there is no recent activity, and assuming in your case not a lot of data is being transmitted, it doesn't use much power for transmissions.

Comment: This is true of many remote stations, but not of the "access point" / host adapter, which can very well communicate with multiple remote stations at once.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question has a rushed assumption based on very limited sample.

The actual power consumption depends more on a software than on a hardware. That is to say that *average* power consumption over the time depends on what the device is doing and how it is configured more than momentary power consumed by the electronics. This is especially true for new BLE protocols.

When the device is idle it may consume almost nothing. However if software activates advertising on a *peripheral* then transmission bursts can take up significant current. Moreover, the length of transmissions depends on the amount of advertised services and other metadata.

Similarly, active *central* may consume almost nothing when it is not scanning for advertising peripherals.

Going beyond central/peripheral roles, one has to look at *client*/*server* roles. In the simplest setup client software will send request and server will respond. Obviously, power consumption depends on frequency of requests and data length.

However since both central and peripheral can assume either client or server roles and even change them on the fly, it means that software again will determine power consumption.

Going even further, activating server-side notifications does not mean server device will consume more power. The way it is done is that client sends short requests "do you have anything new for me?" and server responds with long data only when it does.

So, when the devices are paired they may consume much less energy (if advertisement and scanning deactivated) or they may consume much more if notifications enabled.

Furthermore, the RF power of the transmitters is also configurable by the software and in BLE 5.2 it can even be adjusted on the fly using RSSI feedback from the receiver.

From all of the above one can see that to make comparative statements it is necessary to take the exact setup into consideration and measure average power consumption over substantial period of time.